# TDM audio interface (2 stereo channel ) with iMX8

Tags: audio

I am working with 2 stereo channel audio (4 ADC) interfaced with iMX8M MINI. I did the single stereo channel interface successfully with the iMX8M MINI board and I am able to record and play the audio using arecord and aplay alsa commands.

[How to combine multiple raw pcm data streams in kernel and route it to a TDM frame to be sent out via SAI interface in iMX 8M Mini](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537455/how-to-combine-multiple-raw-pcm-data-streams-in-kernel-and-route-it-to-a-tdm-fra/605613?noredirect=1#comment1130568_605613)

I understand the changes required for asound.conf (from above link reference) to split the multiple audio channels but i am not much aware about how to read the TDM audio stream. Can we record that simply by like, arecord -f S24_LE -c4 -r4800 -D hw:1,0 test.wav for 4 ADC audio channel. And if yes it is possible to aplay this stream directly.?

Looking for some positive reference.